# Change colour of text in textview

Tags: swift, textview, nsattributedstring

I've got a textview that combines several strings, each separated by a new line.  Each string also has a title, which I'd like to display in a different colour and bolded.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
let summaryText = "Summary \n"
let summaryAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange]
let summaryString = NSAttributedString(string: summaryText, attributes:summaryAttributes)

GoalSettingDetailsTextView.attributedText = summaryString + GoalSettingMoreDetailsSummary + "\n\n" + "Notes \n" + GoalSettingMoreDetailsNotes
```

Here you can see that I've tried to make "Summary" orange.  I've also tried to display the "Notes" title as a normal string without any attributers.  This part works fine.  However, I get an error with "summaryString".

The error is:

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSAttributedString' and 'String'

How can I get this working?

Comment: Use NSMutableAttributedString and its append property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `+` to append with `NSAttributedString`.

Create an `NSMutableAttributedString` and build that up.

```
let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: summaryString)
attrStr.append(GoalSettingMoreDetailsSummary) // not sure what GoalSettingMoreDetailsSummary is
attrStr.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n\nNotes \n"))
attrStr.append(GoalSettingMoreDetailsNotes) // not sure what GoalSettingMoreDetailsNotes is

GoalSettingDetailsTextView.attributedText = attrStr
```

This code assumes `GoalSettingMoreDetailsSummary` and `GoalSettingMoreDetailsNotes` are of type `NSAttributedString`. If they are just `String` then create `NSAttributedString` from them like I did with the literal string.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Prestyler](https://github.com/kruil/Prestyler/). You can just write something like this:

```
Prestyler.defineRule("$", Prestyle.bold, UIColor.red)
label.attributedText = ("$My title$" + nextText).prestyled
```